# output from regex python

Tags: regex, python-2.7

i have this data:
result =

```
Operator       #Hosts   Avg Time   Max Time   #Rows  Est. #Rows  Peak Mem  Est. Peak Mem  Detail
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
01:EXCHANGE         1  136.668ms  136.668ms   1.02K          -1         0              0  UNPARTITIONED
00:SCAN HDFS        1  115.097ms  115.097ms  36.86K          -1  99.97 MB      960.00 MB  edw.dw_loan_int_amt
```

I came up with this regex (r".*?([0-9]+.[0-9]+\ .B).*?[0-9]+.[0-9]+\ .?B.*) to get the information i need from "Peak Mem" in this case output is 99.97MB

What Im trying to do: If result > 90 MB then #do this

Any help appreciated.

This is what i have so far, but im getting: None

```
result = sum_data['summary']
    print result
    m = re.match(r".*?([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\ .B).*?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\ .?B.*", result)
    print m
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split it in lines and then with a simple regular expression like `\s{2,}` (meaning at least two whitespaces, possibly more).

---

In `Python`:

```
import re

data = """
Operator       #Hosts   Avg Time   Max Time   #Rows  Est. #Rows  Peak Mem  Est. Peak Mem  Detail
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
01:EXCHANGE         1  136.668ms  136.668ms   1.02K          -1         0              0  UNPARTITIONED
00:SCAN HDFS        1  115.097ms  115.097ms  36.86K          -1  99.97 MB      960.00 MB  edw.dw_loan_int_amt
"""

rx = re.compile(r'\s{2,}')

for line in data.split('\n'):
    parts = rx.split(line)
    if len(parts) > 2:
        print(parts[6])
```

---

This yields

```
Peak Mem
0
99.97 MB
```

Or - if you prefer a list comprehension:

```
memory_peaks = [parts[6] 
                for line in data.split('\n')
                for parts in [rx.split(line)]
                if len(parts) > 2]

print(memory_peaks)
```

Comment: This works good for that data only, but if data is larger it does not grab all of the peak mem, it grabs some of the #Rows as well. Also I have it in a loop so there are multiple data sets